# Is frame busting javascript required despite x-frame-options

Tags: header, iframe

I am using `x-frame-options sameorigin` header to prevent some of my websites from being loaded in iframes. Is this a foolproof method to prevent iframe loading?

There have been several old threads on stackoverflow that discuss employing frame busing javascript code. One example being:

```
if(top.location!=location)
top.location=self.location;
```

Given that almost all browsers now support x-frame-options, should  I still employ the frame busting code alongside? For example, can an attacker somehow bypass the x-frame-options?

Comment: `x-frame-options` isn't a standard header, you have no guarantees about it's support.

Comment: In addition to x-frame-options, now I have added CSP frame-ancestors (self) as well. Should this be fine? Can both the headers be present...

Comment: you want the fewest headers possible for performance.

Comment: Ok.. I will then remove the XFO and retain the CSP... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for framebusting script now, no. In fact, at this point even `X-Frame-Options` is kind of legacy; the thing you keep around in case somebody is still using IE, but not the primary protection. That should be the new CSP `frame-ancestors` rule, which is both better-standardized than XFO and more customizable than (the common implementation of) XFO. XFO is supported even on browsers from 11 years ago, so old they only run on operating systems already went out of support themselves. Nobody should be unable to use it, not for the usual "sameorigin" or "deny" values.

Framebusting script was also never perfectly reliable. The number of people who browse with strict NoScript or similar probably exceeds the number the number who use browsers that don't support XFO, even though script is pretty essential to the modern web. These days, if I wanted to get around framebusting code, that's easy - iframe with the `sandbox` attribute blocks script inside the frame - whereas there's no way for an attacker to disable XFO (or CSP) unless the page is served over plain-text HTTP and the attacker has a man-in-the-middle position on the network.

Comment: I understand that someone can use sandbox attribute and thereby render the frame busting code useless. But in my specific case, I think if someone somehow renders my pages in an iframe without js enabled, that doesn't pose much of a risk (as my application's functionality depends on JS anyways).  Regarding the CSP header (and XFO) I could find some vague references on the internet that say an attacker can strip headers. Is that possible?

Comment: Not meaningfully. Stripping headers - or doing *anything* else other than blocking traffic wholesale and blindly - is impossible over HTTPS (or any other TLS connection), absent any serious security vulnerabilities in the protocol (some very old versions might be vulnerable) or exposure of the private key (and even then, it'd have to be at the right time). You probably found references to attacks carried out on plain-text HTTP (which is easy to edit, if you can get on the network between endpoints) or via a proxy (that terminates TLS and thus can edit the HTTP).